# QTP - Dynamic in nature

Tags: qtp

we have one object in which that object keep on changing(Dynamic in nature) like webedit , next time web button . how will you handle this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What actions are you doing on this element?
The intersection of what you can do with a `WebEdit` and a `WebButton` is pretty much `WebElement`.

Try changing the test object to `WebElement` and see if this fits your needs.

Comment: ok. Last week i was asked in interview that "tell me few reusable function" . Could you tell me the answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

First try with the Test Object if it works.Its fine

Otherwise you need to use descriptive programming , check the child elements .Either it is WebEdit or WebButton and use If..Else block to write the code as per your necessity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **"setTOProperty"** and in that you can change the property to the desired one.

```
obj.setTOProperty("micClass","WebEdit")
```

Hope this would solve the problem statement.